# How to hide the windows 10 taskbar close button using WINAPI?

Tags: winapi, button, hide, taskbar

I need to find a way to remove this button:

[image: Taskbar close button]

I already tried to put the `CS_NOCLOSE` flag into the `WNDCLASS`, but this is not working.

```
  WNDCLASS    wc;
  wc.style         = CS_OWNDC | CS_NOCLOSE;
  wc.lpfnWndProc   = (WNDPROC)staticWindowProc;
  wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
  wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
```

I also have this code inside the callback:

```
case WM_INITMENU:
  EnableMenuItem((HMENU)wParam, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_DISABLED); 
  break
```

Comment: Can't you show us a [mcve] of how you registered your window class and then created the window

Comment: `CS_NOCLOSE` disables the close button (and menu entry), but it will not remove it. Your error description (*"[it] is not working"*) is lacking. How so? Is the button still clickable? Does it make funny noises when you do? Did it turn green? Something else?

Comment: The only way to remove the button is to give up on the system menu completely.  You have to omit the WS_SYSMENU style flag in your CreateWindowEx() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way to disable the close button but I have hidden my window from the taskbar as explained here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144179(v=vs.85).aspx#tbnotify_Taskbar_Display_Options (section Managing Taskbar Buttons)) using the WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW flag.

Thx for help